# Windows Phone prevent ScrollViewer "over scrolling" behavior

Tags: windows-phone, scrollviewer, overscroll

My form contents are displayed in a Grid inside of a Scrollview on a page.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="DS.Mobile.Pages.FormAppPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
>

<ScrollViewer >

    <Grid x:Name="_canvas" Background="Gainsboro">
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Normally the content can be viewed without any scrolling action, but windows provides a dramatic over scrolling behavior anyway if you drag across the screen surface. How do you prevent this over scroll behavior?

Comment: If this is what happens in other apps too id leave it so your consistent with the os.

Comment: Agreed if the content needs to scroll at all, but if not it's really inappropriate for my content.